# UICollectionView & AVPlayer Performance

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a `UICollectionView` whose cells each have an `AVPlayerLayer`, all playing a video at the same time. About 9 cells fit on the screen at a time and it's pretty laggy so I need ways to boost the performance to achieve smooth scroll. There's a few things I've tried already:

1) Each cell has only one instance of `AVPlayer`. It doesn't get created, instead, `player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayer` is called when the video url changes.

2) Because I'm using ReactiveCocoa, it's trivial to skip repeat urls to avoid playing the same video twice.

What else can I do to speed up the scroll and performance?

Comment: Keep in mind that an AVPlayer that is not playing an item takes up no resources, only after. To reduce the resource usage/memory consumption, set the AVPlayer's player item to nil.

Comment: Here's my latest iteration of a perfectly smooth-scrolling collection view with real-time video previews (up to 16 at a time:  https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg  It even uses a cover flow custom layout and "reflection" view that mirrors the video preview perfectly.  The source code is here:  http://www.mediafire.com/download/ivecygnlhqxwynr/VideoWallCollectionView.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to say it's a bit crazy to see several players in action at the same time: it's a heavy task of rendering anyway.

As far as I know, simply scaling/re-framing the video to smaller size doesn't make it less content to render: if you have a 100x100 picture to render and you render it in a frame of 10x10, it still consumes the same amount of memory as the original picture would consume; same thing goes for videos. So, try to make your video assets having similar resolution as the frame where you would present them.

Comment: I'm aware of that but do you have any other possible solutions?

Comment: Hmm not really. If scrolling gets laggy when cells just about to appear, it's probably because of the heavy nature of initializing/using multiple AVPlayers. And it's perhaps one of the reasons why only one instance of MPMoviePlayer can exist at any time.

Comment: What about doing something like this: https://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell? I'm not sure if such a custom solution is relevant with iOS 9 or not.

Comment: The repo doesn't have descriptions/docs, and the only link doesn't seem to work .... You might want to explain a bit what's that repo trying to do

Comment: It's Loren Brichter's custom cell solution for fast scrolling. He's the guy that made tweetie and invented the pull to refresh gesture.

Comment: @startupthekid correct me if im wrong, but it seems that the repo just has two files and the .m file doesn't really have too much to combat performance issues.

Comment: From what I understand, the key method there is `drawContentView`. Apple actually incorporated it into their example source code. "Apparently" it makes cells render much much faster

Comment: My understanding about ABTableViewCell is that it basically makes the cell only renders things once instead of having subviews and renders multiple times and thus helpful for complicated cells. But my guess is that it might not help in your case as you are doing movie playing.

Answer (score 2):

Store each cell in an NSCache or NSMapTable using the NSIndexPath as the key for each; then, whenever you need a cell, call one directly from the cache or map table.

Obviously, you'll have to create all the cells at once, but you'll get the same scrolling performance as you do with nothing in the cells at all.

Need sample code?

Here's my latest iteration of a perfectly smooth-scrolling collection view with real-time video previews (up to 16 at a time):

https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg

It even uses a cover flow custom layout and "reflection" view that mirrors the video preview perfectly.  The source code is here:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/ivecygnlhqxwynr/VideoWallCollectionView.zip

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, UIKit will hit bottlenecks and drop frames when put under pressure for this use case. If you can muster refactoring code to use Facebook's AsyncDisplayKit / then this would be your best bet.

For objective-c / this project here is a good reference.
https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/tree/master/examples/ASDKTube

```
- (ASCellNode *)tableNode:(ASTableNode *)tableNode nodeForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  VideoModel *videoObject = [_videoFeedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  VideoContentCell *cellNode = [[VideoContentCell alloc] initWithVideoObject:videoObject];

  return cellNode;
}
```

there is swift code available if you dig deep enough in github.